# Why are my Network Analyst generalized polygons not being drawn correctly?

Tags: arcmap, network-analyst

I've created a service area using ArcMap with the Network Analyst extension.  The line generation appears to be pretty accurate, however, the polygon generation isn't what I'm expecting.  I'm looking for a nice, general outline of the service area however, I'm getting a very detailed polygon regardless of my Generalized/Detailed setting or my Trim setting.

Here's some examples:

**Generalized Polygons**
[image: generalized]
Here, I'd expect to see the large white area gaps between extended areas to be filled as general (basically connecting the most distant points, along each road).  Instead, it appears that it's only filling one side of streets-but I cannot find a setting that's forcing that to occur.  I built the road network used in the model, and it's a derivative of a version that's worked as anticipated in the past.  *Ignore the green line segments, they're left over from a prior layer.*

**Generalized Polygons, trimmed to 200 feet**
[image: generalized_trimmed to 200 feet]

**Detailed Polygons**
[image: detailed]

**Detailed Polygons, trimmed to 200 feet**
[image: detailed_trimmed to 200 feet]

UPDATE:
Interestingly, when I selected Use Hierarchy (under Analysis Settings) and turned off lines, I got something more like I was expecting.  But I'm not sure why.
[image: generalized_with hierarchy]